# Javascript Compare Object key and array and return new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop, es6-class

Could you please help in achieve below output compare var1 and var2 and obtain output based of var2 where key are provided in string of array

```
var1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4};
var2 = ['a', 'd'];
```

## Output should be:

```
var3 = {a:1, d:4};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const var3 = var2.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (var1[cur]) {
    acc[cur] = var1[cur];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chp510nj/

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have use case. where key is not available in array for example. var var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var var2 =['a','d','f']; i have output like var3 = {a:1, d:4};

Comment: @GauthamShetty a simple `if` will solve that. see edit

Answer (score 0):

Using `.forEach`

```js
var var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var var2 =['a','d'];
var var3 = {};

var2.forEach(i=>{
 var3[i] = var1[i]
})


console.log(var3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have use case. where key is not available in array for example. var var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var var2 =['a','d','f']; i have output like var3 = {a:1, d:4};

Comment: I didn’t get you. The case you provided would still work with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.map()` each key in `var2` to an object containing the key and its associated value. From that mapped array, you can assign each object to an object using `Object.assign()`:

```js
const var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
const var2 = ['a','d', 'f'];

const var3 = Object.assign({}, ...var2.map(id => id in var1 ? {[id]: var1[id]} : {}));
console.log(var3);
```

Another approach could be to use `Object.fromEntries()` if you can support it:

```js
const var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
const var2 = ['a','d', 'f'];

const var3 = Object.fromEntries(var2.filter(id => id in var1).map(id => [id, var1[id]]));
console.log(var3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have use case. where key is not available in array for example. var var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var var2 =['a','d','f']; i have output like var3 = {a:1, d:4};

Comment: @GauthamShetty I've updated my answer to handle these cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries and iterate

```
var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var2 =['a','d'];
o={}
for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(var1)){
  var2.forEach(x=>{if(k==x){
        o[k]=v
  }})
}
console.log(o)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have use case. where key is not available in array for example. var var1 = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}; var var2 =['a','d','f']; i have output like var3 = {a:1, d:4};